# how to define upper bounds for scala method

Tags: scala

how do you define a Scala method such that it would take in the subclass of any type A without throwing a compilation error?

```
trait A
case class B extends A
case class C extends A
case class W[T](abc: Option[T]= None)

def methodOne(a: A): W[A] = {
  a match {
     case b:B => methodTwo() // throws compilation error
     case c:C => methodThree() // throws compilation error
  } 
}
def methodTwo(): W[B] = y
def methodThree(): W[C] = z
```

Have tried something like

```
def methodOne[T <: A](a: A): W[T]
```

but it doesn't allow to compile still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want forall `T <: A` to imply `W[T] <: W[A]`, you need to make `W` covariant:

```
case class W[+T](abc: Option[T] = None)

object X {
  def methodOne(a: A): W[A] = {
    a match {
      case b: B => methodTwo()
      case c: C => methodThree()
    }
  }

  def methodTwo(): W[B] = ???
  def methodThree(): W[C] = ???
}
```

For basic coverage of variance, see [this post](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `W` covariant. You can do this easily by defining it as `W[+T]`:

```
case class W[+T](abc: Option[T] = None)
```

This way if `B` is a subtype of `A`, `W[B]` is also a subtype of `W[A]`.

`Option` for example is defined as `Option[+T]`, therefore `Option[B]` is a subtype of `Option[A]`.

You can checkout [the official scala docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html) for more details